# How does this "common idiom" actually work?

Tags: go, variable-assignment, slice, scanline

Looking at documentation for [golang's 2D slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#two_dimensional_slices) and cannot understand the syntax used in the last example:

```
func main() {
    XSize := 5
    YSize := 5

    // Allocate the top-level slice, the same as before.
    picture := make([][]uint8, YSize) // One row per unit of y.

    // Allocate one large slice to hold all the pixels.
    pixels := make([]uint8, XSize*YSize) // Has type []uint8 even though picture is [][]uint8.

    // Loop over the rows, slicing each row from the front of the remaining pixe ls slice.
    for i := range picture {
        picture[i], pixels = pixels[:XSize], pixels[XSize:]
    }
}
```

I found the [change request](https://codereview.appspot.com/7423051/diff/6001/doc/effective_go.html) where this was added to the docs and the change author had this normal / easy to understand code:

```
// Loop over the rows, slicing each row.
for i := range picture {
     picture[i] = pixels[i*XSize:(i+1)*XSize]
```

However, there is the following comment:

> fine. another common idiom is to avoid the math:
>
> `picture[i], pixels = pixels[:XSize], pixels[XSize:]`

My question is how does the above achieve the same as the !"avoid the math" method? Some docs on what is going on would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
picture[i], pixels = pixels[:XSize], pixels[XSize:]
```

Is a tuple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments). It assigns a value to `picture[i]` and a value to `pixels`. The values assigned in order are `pixels[:XSize]` and `pixels[XSize:]`.

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation). Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

What happens here is that when the loop starts (`i = 0`), the first element of `picture` (the first row) is assigned with a slice value being the first `XSize` elements in `pixels`, and the `pixels` slice is resliced so its first element will be the `XSize`<sup>th</sup> element +1.

So in the next iteration `picture[i]` will be the 2nd element in the `picture` (the 2nd row), and again, the first `XSize` elements from `pixels` will be set to it as a slice. But since in the previous iteration we resliced `pixels`, in each iteration its first `XSize` elements will be the subsequent rows.

Comment: Awe right. Totally makes sense. `(picture[i], pixels) = (pixels[:XSize], pixels[XSize:])`. Just wasn't seeing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

This tuple assignment example can be rewritten like:

```
for i := range picture {
    picture[i]= pixels[:XSize]
    pixels = pixels[XSize:]
}
```

It's now easier to see that *picture* is this first *XSize* items of *pixels*.

And that  *pixels* **is modified** at each loop and drops its first *XSize* items.